# SQL Where IN Order 2 SubQuery

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables in SQL :

```
video : ID, TITLE
join_video_clicked : ID_VIDEO, NB_VIEW
join_video_category : ID_VIDEO, ID_CATEGORY
```

My actual SQL Query :

```
SELECT ID,TITLE,THUMB 
FROM video 
WHERE ID 
IN (
      SELECT * FROM 
      (
         SELECT ID_VIDEO 
         FROM join_video_clicked
         WHERE ID_VIDEO 
         IN 
         (
             SELECT ID_VIDEO 
             FROM join_video_category 
             WHERE ID_CATEGORY = 8
         ) 
    ORDER BY CLICKED DESC
  ) AS TEMP
 ) LIMIT 0,24
```

Explain 1 :

```
SELECT ID_VIDEO FROM join_video_clicked ORDER BY CLICKED DESC LIMIT 0,24
```

This query get 24 ids the most viewed

Explain 2 :

```
SELECT ID_VIDEO FROM join_video_category WHERE ID_CATEGORY = 8
```

This query get ids from custom category

Explain 3 :

```
SELECT ID,TITLE FROM video WHERE ID IN (!!!SUBQUERY!!!)
```

This query find id and title with subquery

I would like your help for adjust my query for get 24 most viewed video from custom category in correct order, because with this query i have the 24 video most viewed in my custom category but not in order DESC.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT ID,TITLE,THUMB FROM video v JOIN join_video_clicked jvc ON 
ID=jvc.ID_VIDEO JOIN join_video_category jvcat ON ID=jvcat.ID_VIDEO WHERE 
ID_CATEGORY = 8 ORDER BY CLICKED DESC LIMIT 0,24
```

Comment: #1052 - Column 'ID' in field list is ambiguous

Answer (score 0):

You can do an inner join between the two tables to get all videos from that category, and in that query you can add your order by and limit:

```
SELECT jvclick.id_video
FROM join_video_clicked jvclick
JOIN join_video_category jvcat ON jvcat.id_video = jvclick.id_video
ORDER BY jvclick.clicked DESC
LIMIT 24;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it:

```
select
    vid.id_video,
    vid.title,
    count(click.id_video) cnt
from
    video_clicked click
    join video vid on click.id_video = vid.id_video
    join video_category cat on vid.id_video = cat.id_video
where
    cat.id_category = 1
group by
    vid.id_video,
    vid.title
order by 
    cnt desc
;
```

Full example:

```
use example;

/*
video : ID, TITLE
join_video_clicked : ID_VIDEO, NB_VIEW
join_video_category : ID_VIDEO, ID_CATEGORY
*/

drop table if exists video_clicked;
drop table if exists video_category;
drop table if exists video;
drop table if exists category;

create table category (
    id_category int primary key,
    name varchar(256)
);

create table video (
    id_video int primary key,
    title varchar(256)
);

create table video_category (
    id_video int references video(id),
    id_category int references category(id)

);

create table video_clicked (
    id_video int references video(id),
    nb_view varchar(256)
);

select
    vid.id_video,
    vid.title,
    count(click.id_video) cnt
from
    video_clicked click
    join video vid on click.id_video = vid.id_video
    join video_category cat on vid.id_video = cat.id_video
where
    cat.id_category = 1
group by
    vid.id_video,
    vid.title
order by 
    cnt desc
;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT v.ID,v.TITLE,v.THUMB FROM video v 
JOIN join_video_clicked jvc ON v.ID=jvc.ID_VIDEO
JOIN join_video_category jvcat ON v.ID=jvcat.ID_VIDEO
WHERE jvcat.ID_CATEGORY = 8 ORDER BY jvc.CLICKED DESC LIMIT 24
```